# Mac Mini Not Connecting to Internet

Tags: network, wifi, airport, mac-mini

My mid 2011 Mac Mini will not connect to the internet properly. I believe it is running Mountain Lion OS.

Occasionally it works very slowly, but is more consistent with not connecting at all, even though the wifi signal appears to be connected.

There is another computer (mid 2010 MacBookPro) that is able to use the wifi just fine. The router/modem is plugged into a Roku box directly.

Things I've tried:

1. To Renew the DHCP lease in the network settings via online tutorials.
2. Engaging Time Machine to take me back to when the settings were working.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Does it work when connected to the router over ethernet? Does this Mac Mini work from another wifi network, such as your phone's? Also, what is the behaviour? Is a browser reporting 'no internet'? Can you ping a known service like google.com from a terminal? Might be the Mac Mini's wifi card is kaput. If ethernet provides better connectivity then this is more likely.

Comment: Thanks for the troubleshooting tips @Jangari… still have not had time to try them all. Hold tight and I will let you know what I discover.